# Migrating Coveralls Report from Travis-CI to GitHub Actions

Tags: travis-ci, github-actions, coveralls

I followed this setup guide: [Integrating with coveralls.io](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/blob/master/docs/setup-coveralls.md)
This was perfect for Travis-CI, using coveralls and nyc. But recently when migrating to GitHub Actions, that step started failing with this error:

```
> js-big-decimal@1.3.3 coverage /home/runner/work/js-big-decimal/js-big-decimal
> nyc report --reporter=text-lcov | coveralls


/home/runner/work/js-big-decimal/js-big-decimal/node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js:19
      throw err;
      ^
Bad response: 422 {"message":"Couldn't find a repository matching this job.","error":true}
(Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

What is the best way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

- Edit the coverage script in package.json to use the default reporter of lcov

```
"coverage": nyc report --reporter=lcov
```

- Modify the pipeline to use the official Coveralls stage

```
    - name: Test
      run: |
        npm run ci-test
        npm run coverage

    - name: Publish to coveralls.io
      uses: coverallsapp/github-action@v1.1.2
      with:
        github-token: ${{ github.token }}
```

---

Originally posted on [Ones and Zeros](https://ones-zeros.royniladri.dev/migrating-coveralls-report-from-travis-ci-to-github-actions)